# What Maven repository should I use to obtain tomcat jars?

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, gradle

I’m trying to use Gradle to build a project that will run an imbedded instance of Tomcat. I want to use the Tomcat jar files as dependencies on my project, not use a Tomcat plug-in to run a web app. The main Maven repository doesn’t appear to have Tomcat in it, and the only repository I found with Tomcat is < http://tomcat.apache.org/dev/dist/m2-repository/org/apache/tomcat/> which is fairly out of date. The last version of Tomcat 7 that appears to be available in that repository is 7.0.2 and Tomcat 7 is now up to 7.0.19

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main repository does have Tomcat 7 jars. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/maven-jars.html

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-api</artifactId>
   <version>7.0.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Above is a sample dependency. Perhaps you are using the wrong groupId.

Comment: For some reason our Maven mirror wasn't automatically picking up the Tomcat Jars. When I manually added that maven repository and use a proxy server it works like a charm.